# Time conversion from ticks to data time in scala

Tags: scala

I am trying to convert time in ticks to date in scala. couldn't find any useful approach. sample ticks '636287933517148416L' which represents '2017-04-26T08:49:11.714Z'.

Answer (score 1):

Using time from java 8:

```
import java.time._
val ticksSinceEpoch = 621355968000000000L
val ticksPerMilliseconds = 10000

LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli((636287933517148416L - ticksSinceEpoch)/ticksPerMilliseconds), ZoneId.of("UTC"))
```

Comment: Thanks for the help @nmat but I am using java 1.7 and I am not sure if I can use your approach and I have already solved the problem as stated below

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem with the below code. Hope this helps others who may face the same problem. You can convert this into a function where ticks will be the argument for it and it will return the string as in my case I wanted a string output

```
val output = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")
output.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST"))
val ticks=636287933517148416L
val TICKS_AT_EPOCH = 621355968000000000L;
val TICKS_PER_MILLISECOND = 10000;
println(output.format(new Date((ticks - TICKS_AT_EPOCH) / TICKS_PER_MILLISECOND)).toString())
```